# How to make the subprocess handle the ctrl-c?

Tags: python, subprocess, signals

I have a python file parent.py as a wrapper to launch another python program child.py. This is the main part of parent.py:

```
p = subprocess.run(f"python -u {cmd} 2>&1 | tee -a {file_path}", shell=True)
```

I want to use ctrl-c to control the child process. So in the child.py, I wrote a try-except to catch KeyBoardInterrupt and handle it:

```
try:
    while True:
        pass
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("lalala~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
```

However, if I run the parent.py and then press ctrl-c, the parent has been terminated and the child.py cannot handle the interrupt (no "lalala" output):

> ^CTraceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/home/zxl/rcd_python1.py", line 27, in 
> p = subprocess.run(f"python -u {cmd} 2>&1 | tee -a {file_path}", shell=True)   File
> "/home/zxl/programs/anaconda3/envs/pyg2/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py",
> line 495, in run
> stdout, stderr = process.communicate(input, timeout=timeout)   File
> "/home/zxl/programs/anaconda3/envs/pyg2/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py",
> line 1020, in communicate
> self.wait()   File "/home/zxl/programs/anaconda3/envs/pyg2/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py",
> line 1083, in wait
> return self._wait(timeout=timeout)   File "/home/zxl/programs/anaconda3/envs/pyg2/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py",
> line 1808, in _wait
> (pid, sts) = self._try_wait(0)   File "/home/zxl/programs/anaconda3/envs/pyg2/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py",
> line 1766, in _try_wait
> (pid, sts) = os.waitpid(self.pid, wait_flags) KeyboardInterrupt

How can I send the ctrl-c to the subprocess and make it handle it, instead of terminate everything? Thanks a lot~

Answer (score 1):

This is working already.

When you press Ctrl-C, the terminal driver sends a SIGINT to every member of the foreground process group. [1]  In your case, that means each of four processes receives a SIGINT:
`main.py`, it's child shell (*subshell=True*), and that shell's children `child.py` and `tee`.

Your `child.py` correctly handles the SIGINT and prints `"lalalala~~~~"`.  However, this output is piped to `tee`, meaning you'd never see it on the console.  Additionally, `tee` is itself killed by a SIGINT, almost certainly before it has a chance to read from its input and write to its output.  Your `main.py`, since it doesn't handle the SIGINT, dies with the stack trace you observe.

1. [POSIX.1-2017 Base Definitions, *General Terminal Interface*, §11.1.9](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap11.html#tag_11_01_09)

Answer (score 0):

I am getting the output you expect. Your code is working for me.

test_subprocess.py

```
import time

if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        try:
            time.sleep(1)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print("lalala")
```

test_subprocess_main.py

```
import subprocess

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Start')
    p = subprocess.run("python3 test_subprocess.py", shell=True, check=True)
```

The output.

> Mac-sashi:fun sashi$ python3 test_subprocess_main.py
> Start
> ^Clalala
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/Users/sashi/repos/fun/test_subprocess_main.py", line 6, in 
> p = subprocess.run("python3 test_subprocess.py", shell=True, check=True)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File
> "/Users/sashi/.pyenv/versions/3.11.1/lib/python3.11/subprocess.py",
> line 550, in run
> stdout, stderr = process.communicate(input, timeout=timeout)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File
> "/Users/sashi/.pyenv/versions/3.11.1/lib/python3.11/subprocess.py",
> line 1199, in communicate
> self.wait()   File "/Users/sashi/.pyenv/versions/3.11.1/lib/python3.11/subprocess.py",
> line 1262, in wait
> return self._wait(timeout=timeout)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "/Users/sashi/.pyenv/versions/3.11.1/lib/python3.11/subprocess.py",
> line 1997, in _wait
> (pid, sts) = self._try_wait(0)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "/Users/sashi/.pyenv/versions/3.11.1/lib/python3.11/subprocess.py",
> line 1955, in _try_wait
> (pid, sts) = os.waitpid(self.pid, wait_flags)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ KeyboardInterrupt

Can you try the code I posted? Does it work for you?